# Construct a specific base for Fine uniformities in the diagonal(Entourages) case

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

For every uniformizable space $X$ there is a finest uniformity on $X$ compatible with the topology of $X$ called the fine uniformity or universal uniformity.

> To construct Fine uniformities, Let  the family $\{\mathcal{V}_i:i\in I\}$ of all compatible uniformities on $X$ and generates the initial uniformity $\mathcal U$ w.r.t. $id_i:X\to(X,\mathcal{V}_i)$ on $X$. therefore, $\mathcal U$ is finer than each $\mathcal{V}_i$ for $i\in I$. Let us note that, completely regularity is used to show that $\{\mathcal{V}_i:i\in I\}\not=\emptyset$, since $X$ is a completely regular(uniformizable) space and have a compatible uniformity.

Exercise 36H. from Willard, *General Topology* says that,

> The fine uniformity $\mathcal D_F$ on a uniformizable space is the uniformity having for a base $\beta$, the open sets $D\supset\Delta$ such that for some sequence $D_1, D_2,...$ of open sets containing 
>   $\Delta$, $D_n\circ D_n\subset D_{n-1}$ for all $n$ and $D_1= D$.

Is $\mathcal U$ and $\mathcal D_F$ exactly the same uniformity on a uniformizable space $X$? If the answer is yes, then how we can construct a base $\beta$ for $\mathcal U$ ?

---

I am trying to solve this question. $\beta$ is a base for a uniformity on $X$ and the uniformity $\mathcal D_F$ generated by $\beta$ is finer than $\mathcal U$. now it is enough to show that, $\mathcal D_F\subset \mathcal U$. If the $\mathcal D_F$ is compatible with the topology of $X$, then $\mathcal D_F\subset \mathcal U$, since $\mathcal U$ is the finest uniformity on $X$ compatible with the topology of $X$.

Now my problem is to show that $\mathcal D_F$ is compatible with the topology of $X$.

---

I asked this question 3 months ago [[here]](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227170/construct-a-specific-base-for-fine-uniformities-in-the-diagonalentourages-case) but still i can't find the answer. thanks in advice

Comment: The first quote is from where? Why doesn't 36H. answer your question? It's a specific base for the fine uniformity, is it not? Or are you looking for a complete proof.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/a/227702/2060 does not answer the question (in another way?)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I cant find the same definition of the fine uniformity and this question is to show that this two kind of definitions are equal. The first quote is concluded from [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542598/how-can-we-construct-fine-uniformities) and Chapter 0 of Roelcke & Dierolf, _Uniform Structures on Topological Groups and their Quotients_. A complete proof can clear all the problems.

Comment: The answer by Dominic I linked to is the "explicit" construction of the supremum of all compatible uniformities. So by definition almost it induces the fine uniformity (defined as the finest compatible one).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I did not understand how Dominic show that $\mathcal D_F$ is compatible with the topology of $X$. The clarifing about this issue can destroy all ambiguities.

Comment: Also see http://aw.twi.tudelft.nl/~hart/37/publications/the_papers/ency/e07-uniform-spaces-I.pdf (there is a small section on the fine uniformity). Apparently the covers with a locally finite refinement of co-zero sets are exactly the covers in the fine uniformity.